# Why is Python adding special characters to my string?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have some python code that concatenates all my sqlite columns and generates an INSERT command.  When I execute the insert statement I get this:

```
(<class 'sqlite3.OperationalError'>, OperationalError('near "[\'sdf\',
\'sdf\', \'435\', \'fdsg\', \'434\', \'44\', \'dsf\', \'dfg\', \'0\', \'0\']":
syntax error',), <traceback object at 0x02CDF210>)
```

*The error does not contain new lines, it's all one long string.

For troubleshooting, I output the INSERT string prior to command execution. which works flawlessly when I run it inside my sqlite browser:

```
INSERT INTO clients (client_id, firstname, lastname, age, gender, 
phone_number1, phone_number2, email_address, contact_address, total_time, 
total_amt) values ('4','sdf','sdf','435','fdsg','434','44','dsf','dfg','0','0')
```

I am thinking the error has something to do with the '\' , '[',  and  ']' so I passed it through a "scrub":

```
return str(element).translate({ord(i):None for i in "\{}[]!@;:?!.#$"})
```

but nothing changes.  How can I fix this error?  Why is python adding those extra characters?

Here is my python db execution code and the code that generates the values 'list'.
Execution code:

```
formatted_values = admin.format_cols_for_db(cols,'values',client_id,values)
print("INSERT INTO clients {q} values {v}".format(q=query,v=formatted_values))
admin.db.execute("INSERT INTO clients {q} values {v}".format(q=query,v=values))
```

String Code:

```
values = "('" + client_id + "',"
        while i < len(value_li):    #puts into this format: ('4','first','last','33')
            if i < len(value_li)-1:
                values = values + "'" + scrub(value_li[i]) + "',"  
            else:
                values = values + "'" + scrub(value_li[i]) + "')"
            i = i + 1
        return values
```

Comment: Can you post your Python code with insert statement?

Comment: Just did, the copy made me review it for the upteenth time and I realized my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.  I was inserting a list (values) when I should have been inserting my new formatted string (formatted_values).  Took me a few hours to realize my printed output had a different variable than my execution block.

It should read:

```
admin.db.execute("INSERT INTO clients {q} values {v}".format(q=query,v=formatted_values))
```

Rookie mistake...